# PHP Imagick color gray-scale gradient

Tags: php, image, colors, gradient, imagick

I'am new to Imagick and PHP.
The thing I want to make is to put a RGB color on gray-scale gradient.

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image]

The output color may be different. 
Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!
Greetigns,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the colorizeImage function which would do what you asked.

```
function colorizeImage($imagePath, $color, $opacity) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    //TBH - not sure if opacity is meant to be on the color or colorize call
    //neither seem to have much effect.
    $opacity = $opacity / 255.0;
    $opacityColor = new \ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, $opacity)");
    $imagick->colorizeImage($color, $opacityColor);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}


$color = "rgb(252, 38, 231)";
$opacity = 0.5
colorizeImage("someImage.png", $color, opacity);
```

However, why do you want to do it like that? You can just create a colorized gradient directly.

```
$opacity = new \Imagick();
$opacity->newPseudoImage(100, 50, "gradient:rgb(255,128,128,0.5)-none");

//Gradients are created down
$opacity->rotateimage('black', 90);
```

Which creates a perfect gradient in one step.